# Want to clarify and check DFA and NFA attempt

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-expressions, finite-automata, automated-theorem-proving

I did following exercise and i want to clarify that did i made something wrong. And cannot figure out how to solve the c th question.

[Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRbFq.png)

answers that i got

[Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuNMg.jpg)

Comment: Your answer to (b) is alright, but your answer to (a) does not contain a final state... Which states did you mean to be final?

Comment: @AsafHaas aah i forgot to add that q1 must be the final state. i forgot to draw that. :) now, how i figure out C

Comment: I afraid that your answer for (a) is incorrect... Check for example that the word $w = 111$ is accepted by your automata, but $n_1(w) = 0 \pmod{3} $

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2244821/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74295/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I afraid that your answer for (a) is incorrect... Check for example that the word $w = 111$ is accepted by your automata, but $n_1(w) = 0 \pmod{3}$.

Label the states in your answer to (a) as: $$q_0: n_1(w) = 0 \pmod{3}$$
$$q_1: n_1(w) = 1 \pmod{3}$$
$$q_2: n_1(w) = 2 \pmod{3}$$
and try to figure out for each arrow where it should go, what will be the states of $w$.

Here is a NFA for (c):

[image: NFA for (c)]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :). Yeah i made a mistake in a th one. i'll try it again :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to check the DFA that recognizes the set $\{100w001|w\in\{0, 1\}^*\}$

[image]

Comment: I guess the transitions for $q_7$ go into itself?

Comment: Yes it does. Its a trapping state. Sorry I forgot to draw.